# help me understand the drupal way to develop this module

Tags: 7

Coming from a pure HTML, JS, PHP background to drupal 7.x has been a tough transistion, currently I have some code that I would normally use pure JS/PHP to code but I want to make this section managable through the drupal CMS and I'm not totally sure how I would do this. I believe I should be creating a module, but I don't understand how I would create the admin interfaces.

The end result should be structured like this:

- The admin can create 1 or more sessions all of which will be displayed in a drop down.
- Each session will have 1 or more topic listed once selected
- Each topic will have 1 or more files listed under it

For example:

- Session 1
  - Topic 1
    - File 1
    - File 2
  - Topic 2
    - File 1
- Session 2
  - Topic 1
    - File 1

So assuming I create a module and have that module display the data how then do I create the admin page the will allow a user to create 1 or more sessions, with 1 or more topics under each and 1 or more files per topic per session. In pure JS and PHP this is pretty simple and straight forward, in Drupal hell it doesn't seem so easy :(

Comment: How do you intend the end result to display at page level?  There are several ways to attack this depending on what your desired output is.

Comment: exactlly the same as it does here. This is an older site another co worker did in pure JS that I need to adapt to Drupal 7. https://www.musecbt.com/home-practice/

Comment: sareed has suggested exactly what I would in this case.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! "How then do I create the admin page the will allow a user to create 1 or more sessions, with 1 or more topics under each and 1 or more files per topic per session" is a too broad question to be acceptable on this site. If you would have a question about your code that doesn't work, or a question about a better way to write your code, that would be an acceptable question. We cannot teach how to use `hook_menu()` and the form API, nor suggest if it is better creating a custom module or using the Views module.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it would be easier to develop as you have in your example. To make it so that anyone can update let's try to do it a Drupal way. This way may not be the quickest/easiest but it will give you an idea of Drupal and make it easy to update the content.

There are many distros that help make Drupal easier I would suggest [Panopoly](https://www.drupal.org/project/panopoly) to start with. Or you can use core and install the modules as you go (I will probably miss several modules that I am just really used to always being there that are actually contrib).

**1. Custom Content Type**
Create a 'sessions' CT and add the fields and fieldset that you need i.e. 'Read it' and 'Do it'. You can use file fields and [field_collections](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection).

**2. Create View** Use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to create a view of Content Type: 'sessions'. You can create an [exposed filter](http://www.bryanbraun.com/2013/08/06/drupal-tutorials-exposed-filters-with-views) for the drop down.

**3. Create a Basic Page** and add the [view block](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-7/views-module-tutorial/create-block-display) to it (personal preference to suggest views block and not views page for expandability, etc.).

No code this way all GUI. The user would just have to create new content of this type and it would appear on the page.

**Tip:** Use [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) to save your work and provide an exportable default.